# Subversion Automated Path-Based Authorization

Tags: svn

I am trying to find an automated Path-Based Authorization Tool for subversion. Or Reccomendations to how to manage a large auth file more efficiently

Right now we have over 1000 users, 150 groups, and 550 access rules. The auth file is almost 1500 lines.

Managing this size of a repository structure takes time, and ultimately costs money.  There are many duplicate users in the same group, multiple groups that overlap unnecessarily etc.

I have not had any luck finding a more automated solution to managing an auth file of this size. Searching for users, making sure there are no duplicates, adding the user to the correct repository with the correct permissions sometimes 10+ users at a time. Using vi for this task is daunting to say the least.

We have an automated backup script runner that when you run it, it creates a backup, then allows you to modify the auth file.  This is the only prevention to one mistake shutting down the production line.

One tool that I found was suafe.  A good tool, but did not seem to  be an easy way to edit the file from my machine on the server.  Defeats the purpose that I am looking for.

I need a tool that will be able to clean up my current auth file, find duplicates, and add users to the proper repo, create new paths to repos, and new user groups.

Are there any tools, or recommendations that would be beneficial with a repo structure of this magnitude?

FYI: SVN runs on a linux machine.

Comment: I think, you have to start from another point - made your management transparent and documented. After you'll get streamlined business-processes, which answer on "to whom, what, when and why" you can edit authz-file even in text-mode

Comment: The way it is is already pretty documented, and transparent.  Just editing a file with vi is dangerous on a production system.  Accidentally delete a line, or leave dangling erroneous values.  It could shut down the dev process. With over 1000 users, if SVN is down for even one minute, that's 16 work-hours lost. Developers are not cheap, and that's quite a bit of money for one minute of downtime.

With the use of an authorization management tool it would effectively eliminate user error, and make user-management quicker.

Comment: You could use VisualSVN Server's PowersShell to automate access rules management: https://www.visualsvn.com/server/features/powershell/

Answer (score 3):

What if you could change this from being *your job* to ***someone else's** job*?

Subversion using Apache httpd integrates quite nicely with LDAP authentication, and that means (if you're a Windows shop), it will also work with Windows Domain and Active Directory. Windows Active Directory groups become Subversion authentication groups. You can say *this group* (vs. a whole flock of individuals) have access to this section of the repository.

And, if someone needs to be put into a certain group, it's not your job anymore. Instead, they need to be placed into the right Active Directory group, and magically, they'll also get the desired Subversion access too. No changes or documentation with svn_auth files. No more changing svn_access files.

Think of two sets of access to control:

- Read Access
- Write Access

In most shops, Read access is granted to practically the entire repository for all developers. Write access can be controlled by a pre-commit hook or by the Subversion auth and access files.

What I usually do is have a Windows Active Directory group called "Development" that anyone who wants read access to the Subversion repository to belong to. If you have a Windows account, and you're a member of that group, you have access to the Subversion repository.

I then use my pre-commit hook to *fine tune* this access to take away read access for various people for various projects. People can checkout the code and read the code, but they cannot update the code unless they have write permission from my hook. Here's an example of my access setup in the `subversion.conf` httpd configuration:

```
<Location /src>
        DAV svn
        SVNParentPath /opt/svn_repos
        SVNListParentPath on
        AuthType basic
        AuthName "Vegicorp Subversion Repository"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthzLDAPAuthoritative off
        AuthLDAPURL "ldap://ldap.vegicorp.com:3268/dc=vegicorp,dc=com?sAMAccountName" NONE
        AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=SVNRobot,OU=Users,OU=Accounts,DC=vegicorp,DC=com"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "Sw0rdf1sh"
        Require ldap-group CN=Development, OU=Groups, OU=Accounts, DC=vegicorp, DC=com
        Require ldap-group CN=CM-robots, OU=Groups, OU=Accounts, DC=vegicorp, DC=com
</Location>
```

Now, anyone in either the group `Development` or `CM-robots` had access to our Subversion repository.

I then used my [pre-commit](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) hook to control write access. This hook depends upon a Control file for configuration. One of the things I can do is put the control file inside my Subversion repository. This way, managers (because each manager had a separate repository) could edit the Control File and determine who had or didn't have access. This allowed the managers to determine who should and shouldn't have access to their projects without having to go through me.

Comment: Although this sounds like a very good idea, I'm not sure how we would integrate this into our setup.  We do not provide read access to everyone to the entire repository. You are only allowed to see the repo of the project that you are working on.  Giving access to everybody, then taking it away from those who do not need it will be completely backwards from the way it should be.  We have very little project overlap.  Very few people have the clearance to view some of the projects that are in the repository; most don't even know they exist.

Comment: It (LDAP-groups way) will not work, if ACLs must be applied to subtree inside repo (special branches, tags protection)

Comment: @RGG - There are two possible ways to get around this issue: One is to give each group its own repo. After all, if they don't even want read access to other groups, they should logically be separate repos. If you do that, you can define each repo with it's own config `<Location>` and each with its own AD Windows group. I've done this before. Of course, your repositories may be all together into one repo. The other is to try `mod_authz_svn` to setup an Auth file and see if it will work with LDAP groups. It will work with AD Windows users, but I don't know if it will work with LDAP groups.

Comment: @RGG - There is a third way: Why should developers not even be able to see other group's source code? I can understand limiting write access, but read access too? There might be one or two parts that must be hush-hush (like RSA private keys), but setting up a small part of a repo with no-read restrictions for a small group of people isn't a big deal. It only becomes a nightmare if you do this across an entire repo with hundreds of users.

Answer (score 1):

On the rights of delirium:

Have mirror of repos-tree on Windows-host. Manage this mirror with VisualSVN Server - it has good Server-management applet, in which you can manage users/groups/ACLs in GUI-style. And rsync VisualSVN Server's authz file after editing with master

[image]

Comment: I will have to do more research on rsync.  Sounds like it has a good premise, but having the production copy essentially being a backup is mildly frightening.  

Is there possibly an apache front end tool that would do auth file management?

Comment: @RGG - your production **isn't backup** - Win-host may be considered as backup. And you may do not create full copy of production on VisualSVN - you must have synced only repositories trees (without files and other data). Sadly, I don't know any frontend for managing authz for Subversion on independent Apache